# Need to deserialize the json

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class, deserialize

We need to deserialize the json and assign it to a wrapper class..

```
{

  "facet_fields": {
  "CandidateStatus": [
     "Actively Looking Qualified",
     477,
     "Passive Headhunt",
     441,
     "Unqualified",
     39,
     "Placed By Us",
     34,
     "Shortlisted",
     30,
     "Contracting For us",
     21,
     "Not Looking / Found Own Job",
     20,
     "CV Submitted and Pending Review",
     10,
     "Interviewing",
     4,
     "EX-MCP Contractor",
     3,
     null,
     655     ]  
     }
  }
```

Wrapper class

```
public class facet_fields{
    public List<String> CandidateStatus;

    public facet_fields(){
    }
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
facet_fields ff = (facet_fields) JSON.deserialize (jsonstring, facet_fields.class);
```

But we are always getting null.. Any ideas to deserialize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an outer layer in your JSON, so you need to account for that in your class:

```
public class Facet_fields {
    public String[] CandidateStatus;
}
public class Wrapper {
    public Facet_fields facet_fields;
}
public Wrapper parse(String jsonValue) {
    return (Wrapper) JSON.deserialize(jsonValue, Wrapper.class);
}
```

Whenever you get stuck, you might try using [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com) to generate classes from raw JSON to get started.

Comment: Instead of calling JSON.parse, we have to use JSON.deserialize

Comment: @VetriselvanManoharan You're right, I got ahead of myself. Updated this answer. Thanks for the comment.